# pytestで`PytestCollectionWarning`が発生する理由を教えてください

Tags: python, pytest

## 環境

- python 3.6.6
- pytest 4.5.0

## 背景

pytestでテストコードを書いています。フォルダ構成は以下の通りです。

```
tests/
 - test_api.py
 - utils_for_test.py
```

utils_for_test.pyにはテストコードはありません。以下のクラスが存在します。

```py
class TestWrapper:
    """
    テスト用のUtils
    """

    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
```

## 質問

以下のコマンドでpytestを実行したら、以下の警告が発生しました。
`pipenv run pytest tests -v --cov=src --cov-report=html`

```
=============================================================================================== warnings summary ================================================================================================
tests/utils_for_test.py:23
tests/utils_for_test.py:23
  /home/vagrant/Documents/annofab-api-python-client/tests/utils_for_test.py:23: PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'TestWrapper' because it has a __init__ constructor
    class TestWrapper:

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html

----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.6.6-final-0 -----------
Coverage HTML written to dir htmlcov
```

この警告はどのような意味でしょうか？
またどうすれば解決できますか？

私は以下のように考えているため、なぜ「cannot collect test class 'TestWrapper' 」と言われているかが分かりませんでした。

- `utils_for_test.py`はファイル名の先頭に`test`が付いていないので、テストコードとして実行されない
- したがって 'TestWrapper'がテストクラスとして実行されなくて、特に問題ない

#### 参考サイト

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html#internal-pytest-warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `utils_for_test.py` はファイル名の先頭に`test`が付いていないので、テストコードとして実行されない

いいえ。
pytestはデフォルトで、 `test_*.py` と `*_test.py` に一致するファイル名どちらもテスト用モジュールとして読み込みます。
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery

Comment: ファイル名が`utils_for_test.py`のままで、クラス名を`WrapperForTest`という名前に変更したら、解決できました。

Comment: >test prefixed test functions or methods inside Test prefixed test classes (without an __init__ method)

Comment: クラス名のprefixも見るんですね。